# Stripe NodeJS create cutomer in multiple account

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I use stripe-node, I have two account in my stripe dashboard with different secret and publishable key api. When I register my customer, i want to do this simultaneously in both accounts ?

After that my customer will have to select the destination account (in a select drop down) with a new amount to charge the specific account.

What is the best and simple workflow to do that ? Is it mandatory to use stripe Connect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) for this.

What you'd need to do is register one of your accounts as a Connect platform, then connect the other account to the platform using the [OAuth flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#oauth-flow).

You would then be able to collect your customers' card information (using [Checkout](http://zcheck) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements)) with your platform's publishable key, and use the resulting card tokens to [create customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) on the platform's account.

Then, when you need to charge a customer:

- if you want to charge the customer on the platform's account: simply [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) using the customer's ID
- if you want to charge the customer on the other account: first [share the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers) with the connected account, then create a charge on the connected account (using the [`Stripe-Account` header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header)) with the new token

  You can also share the customer then use the new token to [create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) on the connected account, but keep in mind that even though the new customer object (on the connected account) will be independent of the original customer object (on the platform's account). If you update one, you'd need to manually update the other if you want them to stay in sync.

Comment: Sorry, but i can see my connected applications in the connect app settings but when i want to share my customer with this account i have an error : **The provided key 'sk_******' does not have access to account 'acct_**********'** ? Why ?

Comment: @user3703539 Most likely, you're not using the correct API key. I'd recommend writing to Stripe's support at https://support.stripe.com/email so that they can check the logs of your request and help you pinpoint the issue.